# How to programmatically determine the correct launch parameters for a persistent kernel?

Tags: cuda

What is the correct way to programmatically determine the launch parameters of a persistent kernel?  All examples I have found use hard coded values.

Is the following correct?

```
cudaDeviceProp props;

cudaGetDeviceProperties(&props, 0);

int blockCount = props.maxBlocksPerMultiProcessor * props.multiProcessorCount;
int blockThreadCount = props.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor / props.maxBlocksPerMultiProcessor;

//  Gives <<<1312, 96>>> on a RTX 3090
PersistentKernel<<<blockCount, blockThreadCount>>>(...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the following correct?

No.

Use [`cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL.html#group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_1gee5334618ed4bb0871e4559a77643fc1). That will give you both the grid size and block size for the current device which maximizes the occupancy of a given kernel with the minimum number of blocks. That is the optimal launch parameters for a given persistent kernel.

Note that the returned block and grid dimensions are scalars. You are free to reshape them into multidimensional `dim3` block and/or grid dimensions which preserve the total number of threads per block and blocks which are returned by the API.

Comment: Ok but what about the number of threads per block?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you wanted the block size as well. In that case use the API in the edit. It gives both block and grid size for the minimum size to achieve max occupancy on a device

Comment: Ok and to be super clear within the context of my question, you mean use cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize() and then from its out parameters, in the given example: blockCount = minGridSize and blockThreadCount = blockSize

Comment: Yes, the outputs are the block size for maximum occupancy and the minimum number of blocks to full utilize the current device. Just use them as they are returned, or reshape them if you need other dimensionality of the block or grid